# Setting an ImageView from the drawable folder dynamicly

Tags: android, imageview, drawable

Hello developers out there,

I have written a class called Item. Now I want this "Item" to get an image in the constructor from the drawable folder. I already tried to somehow get the resourceId from the images in the drawable folder, but didn't know how, because there is now such function as `imageView.getResourceId()` which isn't the best solution anyway because I would need to temporarly add all images from drawable to an imageView and then get the Id. Is there any way to solve this problem?

Thank you for your help

Comment: please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: don't you want to use like **R.drawable.ic_launcher** ? Share your **Item.java** class please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution:**

Just use this code in java to set the drawable image to ImageView dynamically:

```
your_image_view_object.setImageDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(Your_Activity.this, R.drawable.your_drawable_image));
```

For Example:

```
imageView.setImageDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(MainActivity.this, R.drawable.ic_profilepic));
```

That's it. Hope it helps.

Comment: Glad I could help buddy .. :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
int id = getResources().getIdentifier("yourpackagename:drawable/" + StringGenerated, null, null);
```

This will return the id of the drawable you want to access... then you can set the image in the imageview by doing the following

```
imageview.setImageResource(id);
```